# How to retrieve branch whose tree has been removed and deleted?

Tags: bazaar

I have a bazaar repository holding several branches.  I recently removed one of the trees with `bzr remove-tree path/to/branch` followed by `rm -r path/to/branch`.  Now if I understand correctly, the repository should still hold the branch history, since I never did `bzr remove-branch`.  However, I can't figure out how to retrieve the branch to continue working on it.  Can someone help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `bzr heads --dead` to see the heads (= most recent revisions) of deleted branches, including their global revision ids.

You can then do:

```
bzr branch -r REVISION_ID REPO_DIR BRANCH_DIR
```

Here, REVISION_ID is the id of the head that you want to restore, REPO_DIR is the directory that holds the repository, and BRANCH_DIR is the directory where you want the branch to be stored.

Edit: If the above doesn't work for some reason, you can also do:

```
bzr init BRANCH_DIR
cd BRANCH_DIR
bzr pull -r REVISION_ID .
```

BRANCH_DIR must be underneath the repository directory, of course.

Comment: When I try this, I get "bzr: ERROR: Not a branch: "/home/nathan/[...]": location is a repository.".  I think it's saying that the argument you call `REPO_DIR` must be a branch.  What say you?

Comment: Instead of the repository directory, I specified the directory of the branch on which the branch in question was originally based, and it worked.

Comment: So two questions if you will: (1) `bzr heads` is a bazaar extension; is there any built-in tool that can do the same thing? (2) Why is this branch considered "dead" anyway?  I never did `remove-branch`. I did `remove-tree` plus `rm -r`.  Are these equivalent?  Seems to me that they shouldn't be.

Comment: That's odd. I had tried it before I posted with a repository directory and it worked.

Comment: To clarify: `bzr remove-branch` doesn't delete any revisions or revision history. The revision DAG cannot be pruned, ever. What `bzr remove-branch` basically does is to remove the `.bzr` directory of a branch, unlinking it from the repository. The branch exists, you just don't have a named reference to it. This is why you need `bzr heads` to go through the revision graph and print the (unnamed) branch heads. And yes, I agree that Bazaar has way too much core functionality in extensions.

Comment: If I understand correctly, then `bzr remove-brach path/to/branch` is equivalent to `rm -r path/to/branch/.bzr`, correct?

Comment: Sorry, not quite. I made a small mistake up there in describing it. `bzr remove-branch` removes `.bzr/branch` (i.e., the directory that holds branch information), not `.bzr` proper (which may also hold other information, such as repository or dirstate data).